# How to assign two instances of the same plugins to different markers in a template

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to insert two instances of tt_news on the same page and assign each instance of the plugin to a marker in the template. The two instances would be inserted in a backend column not rendered by my template, like border.

Since inserted plugins have a visible id on the backend, I was thinking about something like this

`page.10.marks.NEWS1 < plugin.tt_news.idxxx
page.10.marks.NEWS2 < plugin.tt_news.idyyy`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... You could either insert content elements at the marker, like so

```
temp.contentElement = RECORDS
temp.contentElement {
    tables = tt_content
    dontCheckPid = 1 # if necessary
}

page.10.marks.NEWS1 < temp.contentElement
page.10.marks.NEWS1.source = UID_OF_NEWS_PLUGIN_ELEMENT
```

or, you could simply completely configure the plugin in ts

```
temp.news1 < plugin.tt_news
temp.news1 {
  # configure
}

temp.news2 < plugin.tt_news
temp.news2 {
  # configure
}

page.10.marks.NEWS1 < temp.news1
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Indeed that helps a lot. Exactly what i was looking for. Plus, pointing directly to tt_content like opens up a world of possibilities for other parts of my site. 
Thank you very much !